# How can I set the values on the Environment tab using New-ADUser with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using a PowerShell script to add users from a CSV file, but I have been unable to find a way to set the values on the Environment tab. I have tried using

```
-OtherAttributes @{'msTSInitialProgram'="programToRun"; 'msTSWorkDirectory'="directoryToRunIn"}
```

to no avail.
I am using Server 2008 R2. Here is the tab I am talking about:

[image: Envionment Tab]

How can I set these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else is interested:

```
$dn  = (Get-ADUser $user).DistinguishedName 
$ext = [ADSI]"LDAP://$dn" 
$ext.PSBase.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesInitialProgram","C:\Temp\test.bat")
$ext.PSBase.InvokeSet("TerminalServicesWorkDirectory","C:\Temp\TestingToTheBone")
$ext.SetInfo()
```

sets the values on this tab.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Create-Active-7e6a3978/view/Discussions